# How to set the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH?

Tags: cmake

I have a problem with the global environmental variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. I already set this and I can see it is set when I type `env`, but when I run `cmake .` to build HipHop, it tells me that the variable isn't set.

Is there a way I can hard-code this into the makefiles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake does not find includes / libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126648/cmake-does-not-find-includes-libraries)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try to run `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/your/path .`

Comment: Is it "-D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=" or "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="?

Comment: It matters, at least for cmake 3.5.1

Comment: I'm really unsure what's going wrong here. I was trying to include opencv in my cmake project, but specifyingthe install directory by setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in the CMakeLists.txt doesn't work for any directory. It only works after setting it via the console command like the one in your answer. Why is that? Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` works as a build directive, rather than as an environment variable. Moreover, you may perform the build into a dedicated temporary directory (it's cleaner, because when done, you can remove that temporary directory and you get back a clean pristine source tree).

```
$ mkdir -p tmpbuild && cd tmpbuild
$ cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/deliveries/hiphop ..
$ make install
$ cd ..
```

Comment: CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is _both_ an environment variable and a build directive:

Comment: why `make install` ?

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS it's different. I had to use:
`make -i CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/the/path"`

This was while installing [VMQT](https://github.com/Rolinh/VQMT), and this error was shown:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:87 (find_package):   By not providing
> "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has   asked CMake
> to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but   CMake
> did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV"
> with any   of the following names:
>
> ```
> OpenCVConfig.cmake
> opencv-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
> "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
> "OpenCV"   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
> has been   installed.

Used this to solve it: `make -i CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.6.0_1/lib/cmake/opencv4/"`