# How do I make cmake find qt to build geant4?

Tags: qt, build, cmake

This is the command I used

```
sudo cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DGEANT4_INSTALL_DATA=ON -DGEANT4_USE_OPENGL_X11=ON -DGEANT4_USE_QT=ON -DGEANT4_USE_QT=ON /Users/diegocoronel10/Desktop/geant4.10.03
```

This is the error

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/diegocoronel10/Desktop/QtInstall/Qt Creator.app/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
dhcp106:Qt Creator.app diegocoronel10$ sudo cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DGEANT4_INSTALL_DATA=ON -DGEANT4_USE_OPENGL_X11=ON -DGEANT4_USE_QT5.7=ON -DGEANT4_USE_QT=ON /Users/diegocoronel10/Desktop/geant4.10.03
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1318 (message):
  Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4InterfaceOptions.cmake:117 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:80 (include)
```

I have been trying to use the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH but I can't figure out how to use it. I have the install folder of Qt but I don't know where the root directory of Qt is. I downloaded the 5.7 version of Qt.

Comment: Have you Qt4 or 5 installed? Also the devel packages? How to use the prefix path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126648/cmake-does-not-find-includes-libraries and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019505/how-to-set-the-cmake-prefix-path

Comment: `I have the install folder of Qt but I don't know where the root directory of Qt is.` - *Root directory* is actually an *install folder*.

Answer (score 0):

This ia always a baffling one!
Here is what should work, assuming your QT 5.7 is in /usr/local/Qt5.7 there should be a directory for the libraries, something like /usr/local/Qt5.7/5.7/clang_64/lib. You want add to your cmake command:

```
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/Qt5.7/5.7/clang_64/lib/cmake
```

Doing so will allow GEANT4 to find the correct version.

Answer (score -1):

Have you build successfully QT 5.7 after download and install it in /usr/local ?

which system you are using ubuntu ?

if you are trying to build only geant4.10.03. you need to installl qt on your system , either you build the package you have downloaded or install it with command : sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev

After successful installation try to run cmake command

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/install-mac.html  I did´t build it, I installed qt using Qt Installers. I am using Mac OS X.

Comment: Should I uninstall and try to install it with the source code in /usr/local?

Comment: you should try to install qt development package  . You do not need to uninstall qt from your system . You can install downloaded qt package via prefix in /Users/diegocoronel10/QtInstall/  . during building of geant , you should import PKG_CONFIG_PATH and PATH variable  from this location /Users/diegocoronel10/Desktop/QtInstall/